# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS mounting Windows 2012R2 file share (DFS)

Tags: 18.04, kernel, mount, windows, sharing

Last week after installing regular patches on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, I started running in to problems with mounting Windows Server 2012R2 Cluster/DFS shares on the said Linux box. My initial fix was shorting the target path of the mount. See below:

Original (works under Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS **4.15.0-142-generic**)

```
//fqdn.domain.tld/data/backup/vmware/vmware-vcenter/ /mnt/local-folder-somewhere cifs user,uid=vcenter-backup,gid=users,credentials=/some-user/.smbcredentials.just-a-hostname,nocase,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,rw 0 0
```

Shorter target path (works under Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS **4.15.0-143-generic**)

```
//fqdn.domain.tld/data/backup/ /mnt/local-folder-somewhere cifs user,uid=vcenter-backup,gid=users,credentials=/some-user/.smbcredentials.just-a-hostname,nocase,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,rw 0 0
```

Using the Original (longer/deeper) target path on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS **4.15.0-143-generic** results in errors like:

/var/log/messages: `localhost kernel: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.`

On CLI when using mount command:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

To be clear, what I did to verify this behavior is rebooting, using the grub menu booting with an older (*4.15.0-142-generic*) kernel. The problem goes away. Rebooting in *4.15.0-143-generic* makes the problem come back.

Any other experiences here that resemble this behavior? What extra information can I supply to have this sorted out?

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Release:    18.04

Codename:   bionic

No problem: Kernel: 4.15.0-142-generic

Problems: Kernel: 4.15.0-143-generic